# Last number in row

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have got xlsx table with this contents:

```
some word | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | next blank cell
next rows
```

In first row I could some numbers, but this numbers haven't got same quantity always. So, I can have got number from 0 to 5, or from 0 to 10. And I need know, where is the last number. I read content with Apache POI library. How can I find last cell with number?

Thank you, I haven't got any ideas - when I have got some idea, idea doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please show us your ideas?

Comment: you can use 
row.getLastCellNum(); 
to get Last col count which starts with first col as zero. or you can use 
row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

Comment: Yes, but in table are next blank cell.
row.getLastCellNum() was one idea

Comment: Do you want the last cell number that is not blank. right?

Comment: Yes, I want the last cell number, that is not blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following

```
    for(i = row.getLastCellNum();i>=0;i--){
        if(row.getCell(i)!=null){
            if(!row.getCell(i).toString().isEmpty())
                break;
        }
    }//now i is the last cell number which is not blank.
```